# Provided a list of sets, $L$, computing an array where each entry $q_i \in Q$ is the family of sets in $L$ that have intersection $k$ with $l_i \in L$

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, algorithms

I have a set of $(l_1, ..., l_N) \in L$ smaller sets, each with $(r_1, ..., r_M) \in R$ integer elements.  I would like create an ordered array of $(q_1, ..., q_N) \in Q$ sets s.t.:

(1) Each $q_i \in Q$ consists of an unordered list of all such $(l_a, ..., l_b) \in L$ with an intersection of size $k$ with $l_i$ - i.e. where $||l_i \cap l_a|| = k, ||l_i \cap l_{a+1}|| = k, ..., ||l_i \cap l_b|| = k$.

(2) If $i$ and $j$ are successive integers, i.e. $j = (i + 1)$, then we have that $q_i \cap q_j \geq 1$

---

If we are guaranteed upper and lower bounds on the number of elements in each $q_i \in Q$, what is an optimal algorithm for generating the ordered array $Q$?  What might be its worst-case time and space complexity, or its average time and space complexity?

---

Here's an example to help illustrate what I'm trying to do...

Take $L =$ {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 1510, 28897}, {1, 12, 557, 204}, {1, 3, 1510, 28897}}

$l_1 =$ {1, 2, 3, 4}; 
$l_2 =$ {1, 3, 1510, 28897}; 
$l_3 =$ {1, 12, 557, 204}; 
$l_4 =$ {1, 3, 1510, 28897}

To generate $q_1$ for $k = 2$, we note that the set $l_1$ has an intersection of size $k = 2$ with $l_2$, an intersection of size $1$ with $l_3$, and an intersection of size $2$ with $l_4$.  So we write $q_1 =$ {2, 4}.  Likewise, we can write $q_2 =$ {1}, $q_3 =$ {}, and $q_4 =$ {1}.  The set of all $q_i$ sets is the set $Q$.

Comment: Is there any relation between k and the i in q_i?  If not, then there is likely an O(M^3) or better algorithm where M is the total number of sets l_i .  Also, I feel there are some constraints
missing which would make the problem more interesting.  Gerhard "Maybe I Don't Understand It" Paseman, 2012.10.20

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman The variable $k$ is always some fixed small, even integer, e.g. k = 2 or k = 4.

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman I would guess the algorithm is worst-case $O(M^2)$ since, for every set $l_i \in L$, you can scan through all $||L||$ sets and add the number of each set satisfying $||l_i \cap l_j|| = k$ to $q_i \in Q$. 

Comment: Indeed.  When I am not clear on a problem, I usually add to an exponent and hedge.  While you might find an O(MlogM) solution, I am still unclear on the problem to provide much insight.  The basic problem is I am unsure if l_i is a number or a set.  If you want me to play more, you may need to post a kilobyte or so worth of a worked out example. Gerhard "Likes To Understand Through Examples" Paseman, 2012.10.20

Comment: Oh. Something just clicked.  You are hoping that there is (for each i) a set l_f(i) that has a nice intersection with both l_i and l_{i+1}?  And further, that the sequence of f(i) will yield a nice pattern of sizes of intersections?  In that case, I am concerned that there may be no known polytime solution.  Gerhard "May Not Need Examples Now" Paseman, 2012.10.20

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman $l_i$ is a set with a few integer elements.  I'll provide an example.

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman Please let me know if the example is unclear!

Comment: It looks like q_i have become sets of indices (which is OK by me), but should not q_3 be the full set 1,2,3,4?  Gerhard "Too Lazy To Brace Properly" Paseman, 2012.10.20

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman, Each $q_i$ is a list of the sets in $L$ that have intersection of size $k$ with $l_i$. The set $l_3$ has no intersection of size $k = 2$ with any of the other sets, so $q_3$ is the null set. Am I being clear? 

Comment: There is some clarity, but there is also something missing. 1) before we do any computation, is k (the intersection size) chosen and fixed for the rest of the computation? 2) In your example, we do not seem to have the required condition that e.g. q_2 cap q_3 is nonempty. Am I right, or am I missing something?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.10.20

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman, $k$ is chosen and fixed from the outset, never changing.  If you'd like me to specify a specific value of $k$, I'll say $k = 2$ or $k = 4$.  If the intersection is not _exactly_ of size $k$, we ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the optimization that you want to take is the following: if j > i and j is in q_i, then i is going to be in q_j.
Here I assume the q_i are sets of indices, and that j is in q_i precisely when l_i intersect l_j has size exactly k.

Beyond that, I see no optimization one can take in the general case, given that k is fixed in advance.  There may be
some special cases, for example when l_i has less than k elements, you can skip processing of it.  Also, if there is
a special order, say you know some l's are subsets of others, then you can do some speedup.

In general though, things won't be much faster than, for all i and j with i < j, computing l_i intersect l_j and
determining if that intersection has the right size.

Now if the goal is to find a value of k such that q_i cap q_{i+1} is nonempty for all i, that may take a little longer,
but there won't be that many distinct values of k to check.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.10.21